# Can search engines index webpages with path after ".html"?

Tags: seo, url, web-crawlers, file-extension

Are search engines able to index a webpage which has a path after `.html`?

Example:

```
http://example.com/about.html/abc/123
```

Is it an acceptable implementation for SEO?

Comment: Are you handling that URL bus JavaScript or is it different source code from the underlying HTML file or a dynamic script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes google is able to index such urls. Consider reading this article [Google’s John Mueller Says File Extensions in URLs Do Not Matter](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-john-mueller-says-parameters-urls-not-matter/246675/amp/)